# Handling iAd fail to receive Ad within Admob Mediation setup

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-simulator, admob, iad

I have setup a basic application as a test, using the AdMob Mediation service.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      // Create a view of the standard size at the top of the screen.
      // Available AdSize constants are explained in GADAdSize.h.
      bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

      // Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
      bannerView_.adUnitID = kAdMobPublisherID;

      // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
      // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
      bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
      [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

      // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
      [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

      GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
      // Make the request for a test ad. Put in an identifier for
      // the simulator as well as any devices you want to receive test ads.
      request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             @"4D047EB9-A3A7-441E-989E-C5437F05DB04",
                             @"YOUR_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER",
                             nil];

 }
```

I am receiving these errors when the application fails to receive an Ad. I believe iAd sends errors quite a bit during test iAd adverts.

```
[AppDeveloper]: ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Application has iAd Network configuration error" UserInfo=0x9fd8d20 {ADInternalErrorCode=4, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Application has iAd Network configuration error}
```

The error is due to not implementing the didFailToReceiveAdWithError. The issue I have is how to implement this method.

I have looked in the iAd Progamming Guide : [iAd Prog Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH4-SW4)

This suggests setting up a method like this...

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
```

However, as my code is not implementing the iAd network directly, it is setup using a mediation service. I am unsure how to change the above method to work.

Answer (score 3):

Because the AdMob framework handles the ad display (even if mediated to other ad sources like iAd), you only need to implement the handling of AdMob banners. If the AdMob framework displays an iAd through mediation, it'll encapsulate it and present it to you like any regular AdMob banner.
Therefore you just need to set the delegate of the bannerView to receive events from the AdMob framework, e.g. let your view controller implement the `GADBannerViewDelegate` protocol and use it as the delegate):

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <GADBannerViewDelegate>
...
```

in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
bannerView_.delegate = self;
```

You can then add various methods to handle ad events, like

```
- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)bannerView didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error;
```

which is called when no ad could be requested. Also useful:

```
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)bannerView;
```

which is called whenever an ad was received successfully. This method is usually used to slide in the ad banner. The passed `bannerView` is always of class `GADBannerView`, but it has a property `mediatedAdView` that contains the actual ad to display (which could be an iAd banner).

Btw, you're preparing an ad request in your code, but you dont't actually use it for loading an ad. You probably also want to move down the `loadRequest:` call and use the prepared request:

```
[bannerView_ loadRequest:request];
```

There's more about the `GADBannerViewDelegate` methods in the AdMob SDK docs at: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate.

Comment: Thanks, could you further explain your last point. Should the loadRequest:request line be at the bottom of the above (qu) code?

Comment: Yes, loadRequest actually starts the request to fetch an ad. The code in your question calls loadRequest with a newly created request object and then creates another request object, configures it (setting test devices) and discards it. The actual running request is not configured (which is what you wanted to do I suppose). The correct order would be:
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.property = value;
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:request];

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed to add line:

```
bannerView_.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I didn't see any errors in your code, just check that bannerView_ is GADBannerView type.